# cannot connect to compuer using vpn

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn

I have a VPN connected well to network of computers.
I'm trying to connect via remote connection to a  computer in this network, but it failed, I can connect to all other computers in this network.
the problematic computer enables connections from remotes and firewall properties defined well.

what can be the cause of that?
thanks

Comment: If all other PC work well and it's 1 PC that has issues and it's in the same network as the other PC, it'll be an issue on that particular PC.

Comment: right, what should I check besides the settings of remote connection and firewall?

Comment: Disable firewall and see if it works. You're sure remote desktop is enabled and NLA option is not selected? Are you using the correct credentials? Can you ping the device?